# How can I run an interface I made using PyQt5 and a Map program I made using Tkinter at the same time?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyqt5, tkintermapview

I am making an interface for an Unmanned Aerial Vehicle. I have a main interface that shows the data I get from the dronekit and the attitude indicator. I made this main interface using PyQt5, first I was going to add a map directly to this interface I made with PyQt5, but the map I used could not functionally work on the interface I made over PyQt5. So I decided to separate the main interface and the map. I made the map using "tkintermapwiever". When I run the two separately, it works smoothly and stably. But since we have a single tool and we will connect through the same server, both programs need to run simultaneously, my research has not yielded any results. I would be very grateful if you can help. Thank you..

I have tried Threading and Processing methods, but they work sequentially, not at the same time. So for example, my main interface opens first, and after I close my interface, my map application opens. It shouldn't be like this, both should open side by side at the same time.
And there's this extra problem:
in the code snippet below, as soon as I import root.tk, the map opens automatically.

block of code where I call two different files and try multiprocessing:

```html
from multiprocessing import Process
from mainMap import root_tk
from mainarayüz import main


def arayuz() :
    p1 = Process(target= main())
    p2 = Process(root_tk.mainloop())
    
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    arayuz()
```

I managed to run both apps together, but after 1 second both apps froze and did not update themselves.

I will send the code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from sarsgui_taslak import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from geopy.geocoders import OpenCage
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont,  QColor
from connecBaglanti import connect, connection_string, vehicle , VehicleMode, LocationLocal
from attitude_indicator import AttitudeIndicator
import datetime
import time
import math
import tkinter as tk
import tkintermapview
import time
import threading
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from connecBaglanti import connect, connection_string, vehicle, lat, lon
from multiprocessing import Process
 
# print("Simülatör başlatılıyor (SITL)")
# connection_string = "tcp:127.0.0.1:5762"
 
# print("Araç şurada bağlanıyor: %s" % (connection_string,))
# vehicle = connect(connection_string, wait_ready=False)
# # lat = vehicle.lsocation.global_relative_frame.lat
# lon = vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.lon
 
opencage_api_key = "52a.........................0"
 
class MainPage(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
         
######MAIN INTERFACE STUFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
 
####################################MAP WITH TKINTER##############################################
def mapgui() :
    lat = vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.lat
    lon = vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.lon
    # create tkinter window
    root_tk = tk.Tk()
    root_tk.geometry(f"{1000}x{700}")
    root_tk.title("SarsGUI Map")
###MAP STUFFFF
    root_tk.mainloop()
 
 
     
def maingui():
    uygulama = QApplication([])
    pencere = MainPage()
    pencere.show()
    sys.exit(uygulama.exec_())
 
 
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyqt_process = Process(target=maingui)
    tkinter_process = Process(target=mapgui)
 
    pyqt_process.start()
    tkinter_process.start()
 
    pyqt_process.join()
    tkinter_process.join()
```

I'm editing again. I only have one request, that the two programs run simultaneously at the same time. It doesn't matter if it is written in one program or not.

Here is the mainarayüz.py file:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from sarsgui_taslak import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from geopy.geocoders import OpenCage
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont,  QColor
from connecBaglanti import connect, connection_string, vehicle , VehicleMode, LocationLocal
from attitude_indicator import AttitudeIndicator
import datetime
import time
import math

opencage_api_key = "5............0"

class MainPage(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       ####stufstufffffff
   def modechange(self, nowmode) :
       ####stufstufffffff

   def rebootcom(self) :
       ####stufstufffffff
   def armcom(self) :
       ####stufstufffffff
   def disarmcom(self) :
       ####stufstufffffff
   def updatearm(self) :
       ####stufstufffffff

   
   def go_right(self) :
       ####stufstufffffff
   def go_left(self) :
       ####stufstufffffff

   def go_forward(self) :
       ####stufstufffffff
   def go_backward(self) :
       ####stufstufffffff
       time.sleep(0.5)
       ####stufstufffffff




   def update_location_and_marker(self):
       ####stufstufffffff
       
   def updatePitch(self, pitch):
       ####stufstufffffff
   def updateRoll(self, roll):
       ####stufstufffffff
   def update(self):
       ####stufstufffffff
   
def main():
   uygulama = QApplication([])
   pencere = MainPage()
   pencere.show()
   sys.exit(uygulama.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

This is the mainMap.py file:

```
import tkinter
import tkintermapview
import time
import threading
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from connecBaglanti import connect, connection_string, vehicle, lat, lon
lat = vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.lat
lon = vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.lon
root_tk = tkinter.Tk()
root_tk.geometry(f"{1000}x{700}")
root_tk.title("SarsGUI Map")
#############stufstufffffff

def clear_previous_marker():
    #############stufstufffffff

# Konum güncelleme iş parçacığını başlatın
def update_position():
    #############stufstufffffff
    while True:
        #############stufstufffffff

#############stufstufffffff

root_tk.mainloop()
```

This is the mapwithGUI.py file that tries to make the interface.py file and the mainMap.py file open at the same time:

```
import subprocess
import time
import os

def run_two():
    
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "mainarayüz.py"])
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "mainMap.py"])

    while True:
        if p1.poll() is not None:
            p2.terminate()
            break
        elif p2.poll() is not None:
            p1.terminate()
            break
        time.sleep(1.0)

    p1.wait(1.0)
    p2.wait(1.0)
    print("Tamamlandı")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_two()
```

In the mapwithGUI.py file, I am trying to make both of them work simultaneously, but at first the map comes up (mainMap.py), after I close it, the interface (maininterface.py) comes up. If I do not close the map, the interface does not come.

The Last Edit:

The dronekit library that I use in both mainMap.py and maininterface.py, where I connect the map and interface to the uav (maybe this is the problem) :

```
from dronekit import Command, connect, VehicleMode, LocationGlobalRelative, LocationLocal,__init__

# print("Simülatör başlatılıyor (SITL)")
connection_string = "tcp:127.0.0.1:5762"

print("Araç şurada bağlanıyor: %s" % (connection_string,))
vehicle = connect(connection_string, wait_ready=False)
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OC-JwTG01P_whg_fw_FkKstUIEjtlm7F/view

THE LAST AND LAST EDIT:

I did it. I put two separate programs under one program like two main functions (as I mentioned above at the beginning). The process method didn't work again, but the threading method did. I think this is related to using the same memory space.

Comment: Why can't you just start the two programs?  I run multiple python programs at the same time on a regular basis.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: It is better to show what you have tried on executing the two programs, otherwise it is hard to identify the issue.

Comment: The whole point of multiprocessing is to allow two processes work *concurrently*. If in your attempt you see them working sequentially, then you did something wrong (probably by calling `join()` on the first process), but we cannot tell you anything about that until you show us a proper [mre] based on your attempts. Note that it's quite possible to show maps within Qt (through the QGIS module), so you don't need to use separate programs at all.

Comment: Note that `target=main()` will execute `main()` immediately and assign return value to `target`.  User `target=main` instead.

Comment: `Process(root_tk.mainloop())` will execute `root_tk.mainloop()` immediately in the main process as well and wait for its termination.

Comment: @acw1668 I did what you suggested but nothing changed, at first the map opens (root_tk.mainloop function), when I close it my main interface opens (function named main).

Comment: @PaulCornelius I am using Linux Ubuntu version 20.06

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your map advice, I will integrate the map into my new interface in the future, but the program I am using now is a bit urgent. So I need to solve this problem, I have added the code fragment I used above.

Comment: You don't need to call `.join()` since both processes are non-daemon process.  Also it is hard to identify the frozen issue because the provided code simply starts two processes with empty windows and nothing seems to be the cause of the frozen issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to run the two GUIs in separate programs.  I'm not sure what specifically you tried with multiprocessing, but that's indeed one way it should be possible to get that running.

There is no good way to make it work in a single program.  Each toolkit needs to have control of the the queue of GUI events in order to respond appropriately.  It might be possible in principle to bridge those with some kind of mapping, but I'm not aware of any existing mechanism for doing that, and if it's possible at all then it is surely much more than you will want to take on personally.

Comment: Actually, I have no intention to combine two separate programs and make a single program. Simply put, I just want to run two different python programs at the same time. I researched the Multiprocessib method and as I said, the programs I wrote ran sequentially, not at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused by your question, since you keep insisting that you have no intention to combine the two GUIs into a single program yet in your code you are trying to do exactly that.  You didn't respond to my comment where I asked why you can't simply run the two programs at the same time, using standard operating system methods. Based on the code you provided, there is no interaction at all between your two programs, so there is no particular reason why they have to be started from the same Python script.  However, putting all that aside and apologizing again for my possible misunderstanding, here is an idea for you:

Step 1 is to separate the PyQt program from the TkInter program.  Put their entry points into two different files, so that they are literally two completely separate programs.  They know nothing about each other.

Step 2 is to launch both programs from the same Python script, using methods in the subprocess module.

Here is an example of how you might do this.  In my case both programs are tkinter programs, but it doesn't matter.  There are three files involved.  First here is a4a.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def test_gui():
    root_tk = tk.Tk()
    root_tk.geometry(f"{1000}x{700}")
    root_tk.title(f"Test program {random.random()}")
    root_tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_gui()
```

It looks a bit like your mapgui() program.  Here is a4b.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def test_gui():
    root_tk = tk.Tk()
    root_tk.geometry(f"{1000}x{700}")
    root_tk.title(f"Test program {random.random()}")
    root_tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_gui()
```

It's exactly the same code, because it's just for illustration. I've put a random number in the window title so I can tell them apart.  In your case, one would be the tkinter program and the other would be the PyQt5 program.

Here is the third file, a4.py:

```
import subprocess
import time

def run_two():
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(["python3.11", "a4a.py"])
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(["python3.11", "a4b.py"])
    while True:
        if p1.poll() is not None:
            p2.terminate()
            break
        elif p2.poll() is not None:
            p1.terminate()
            break
        time.sleep(1.0)
    p1.wait(1.0)
    p2.wait(1.0)
    print("Finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_two()
```

This script launches the two other programs, and checks once per second to see if either if them has been terminated.  If it is, the script terminates the other one and exits.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for all your answers, and you are very kind. I actually answered your question, either you didn't see it or I misunderstood your question. I apologize if you misunderstood it. Now, I want to explain the problem again from the very beginning. I actually contradicted what I wrote at first, as you said with the code I added later. Actually, I always started to try the solution as I wrote it at first, that is, I wanted to run two different programs together simultaneously at the same time. But as I said, it does not work at the same time.

Comment: The programs run sequentially, the map application comes out first, if I terminate it, the interface opens. Obviously this was a very strange situation. Then I gathered them under one program with the code snippet I added, but I tried to do multiprocessing again. What I wanted to show here is that I wanted to leave an idea in the minds of the users here concretely. I think I confused you even more :)

Comment: In the last code I edited, I put both of them in one program and actually both of them opened simultaneously at the same time, but this time both of them froze after one second. I tried the example you gave, again it opens sequentially, not at the same time as I wrote this question in the first place. So the first map opens, after closing the map, the interface program opens. If you want, I can also send you a screen recording if you give me a platform address where we can communicate. Thank you again for everything and I apologize in advance if there has been any misunderstanding.

Comment: "I tried the example you gave, again it opens sequentially, not at the same time as I wrote this question in the first place."  Well, no computer ever made can LITERALLY open two programs at exactly the same time, in the full physics sense of simultaneously down to tiniest fraction of second.  If that's what you want, I am afraid your are living the wrong universe.  When I run my program, both windows open and remain visible on the screen at the same time.  They are running concurrently.  I do not know what else you can make a computer do.

Comment: Are your programs running concurrently in this manner?  I am also running Ubuntu, so I imagine that you're seeing the same thing I am when you run my program.  Given my statement that no computer can start two programs with perfect simultaneity, how close do you want to come to this ideal situation?

Comment: What I want is certainly not perfect synchronicity. On my computer it works in a sequential way. two programs don't run at the same time. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. which you are probably also using ubuntu. as I said, the two windows don't open at the same time. first the map window opens, then if I close the map window it switches to the interface. this is exactly what I want to explain, I will upload a video link here as soon as possible. Because I guess I can't explain what I want. I apologize in advance if there is a misunderstanding.

Comment: Okay, you say that "it" switches to the interface only after you close the map window.  But that is NOT how my program works, as I've already explained.  On my program, both windows are open and both programs are running at the same time.  There is no "map window" and "interface", there are just two windows and therefore two completely independent applications.  Both are Python applications but that does not matter.  Is that what you observe, too, when you run my program?  If you open your map window, can you then open ANY OTHER application while the map window is still open?

Comment: Sorry I had not noticed the edit you made.  What you describe makes no sense at all, given the logic of the program: when one window closes, the program logic will close the other one.  You're saying something completely different.  So, where does the mapwithGUI program stop to wait for the closing of the first window?  It must be stuck on a particular line, for reasons that are far beyond my understanding.  Can you put a bunch of print statements in it, so you can see exactly what it's doing?  Also, what if you start the programs in the opposite order - gui first, then map?

Comment: One more question: how do you start the program?  Jupyter notebooks, and also IDLE, have strange interactions sometimes with Processes.  Try running mapwithGUI from a command prompt, if that is not already what you are doing.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OC-JwTG01P_whg_fw_FkKstUIEjtlm7F/view?usp=sharing I hope that is clear

Comment: I tried deleting your command to close one window and close the other window

Comment: I watched your video.  As in my last comment, I suspect there is an interaction between your IDE and Python's subprocess.  Please try launching your program from a terminal.  Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969662/run-multiple-python-scripts-at-the-same-time

Comment: If I delete the while loop from my example program, here is what I observe: both windows open, and both remain on the screen.  The script exits with a Timeout error, as the result of the first p1.wait() throwing an exception.  This does not close either window, so the subprocesses are still running.  That is quite different from the behavior you are describing.  Since we are running the same OS (or almost the same), the only difference is that I launch the program from the command prompt and you use VSCode.  Try launching from the command line, please.

Comment: Well, could this problem be related to the dronekit library I am using?

Comment: I tried what you suggested, I even tried directly from linux's terminal, I opened main interface.py in a separate terminal and mainMap.py in a separate terminal, but no luck.```WARNING:dronekit:Link timeout, no heartbeat in last 5 seconds```

Comment: I think you need to get creative about the troubleshooting process.  Have you tried running my ORIGINAL script from the command line, and do you see two windows open at the same time?  You might try launching each of my programs, a4a.py and a4b.py, in separate terminals.  You might try launching one of my programs, a4a.py for example, and THEN launching your mainmap.py in a separate terminal.  You might try launching mainmap.py FIRST, and then interface.py second.  There must be a _reason_ why these programs do not behave like other programs.  Sorry but I do not know anything about dronekit.

Comment: I have done everything you said but NOTHING has changed. Even though I change the order, the first map always opens and the interface doesn't open until I close it. No matter where I run it, the problem is not solved:(

Comment: So what you are saying is that on your Ubuntu box, you cannot run two programs at the same time.  Because the two programs you are describing are completely unrelated to each other.  Can Ubuntu ever show more than one window on the screen at the same time? You cannot seriously think that the answer is "no."  If you start the map, can you open ANY other program while the map is open?  A word processor, a web browser, an email client, anything.  Your question seems like it has to do with how you are using your system.  I hope you are not still starting the programs from inside VSCode.

Comment: I DID IT. I put two separate programs under one program like two main functions (as I mentioned above at the beginning). Process method didn't work again but threading method worked. I think this is related to using the same memory space. Also, I think the dronekit library is linked to a program, I don't understand it, but I will investigate. I am very, very grateful to you for trying to help.